# Wrong Class Table Inheritance

Tags: mysql, cakephp, multiple-inheritance

I have some problems with this mysql relation in CakePHP

**Classes**

```
class User extends AppModel{

}

class UserProfessor extends AppModel{
    public $hasOne = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'joinTable' => 'users',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        ) 
    );
}


class UserStudent extends AppModel{
    public $hasOne = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'joinTable' => 'users',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        ) 
    );
}
```

**DB tables**

Users: id, name, surname, email

User_Professors: id, user_id, coordinator (coordinator is just for students)

User_Students: id, user_id

**Query**

$this->Project->Find('all')

**Result Query**

```
'Student' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=3)
              'id' => string '1' (length=1)
              'user_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'Professor' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=4)
              'id' => string '1' (length=1)
              'user_id' => string '2' (length=1)
              'coordinator' => boolean true
```

***But, where is name, surname and email from User? I want an array like this:***

```
'Student' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=3)
              'id' => string '1' (length=1)
              'user_id' => string '1' (length=1)
              'name' => string 'EXAMPLE'
              'surname' => string 'EXAMPLE'
              'email' => string 'EXAMPLE@EXAMPLE.com'
      'Professor' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=4)
              'id' => string '1' (length=1)
              'user_id' => string '2' (length=1)
              'coordinator' => boolean true
              'name' => string 'EXAMPLE'
              'surname' => string 'EXAMPLE'
              'email' => string 'EXAMPLE@EXAMPLE.com'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are calling function ``find`` on a model ``Project`` is this correct?

Comment: Yes, project has student and professor

Comment: Then please write the associations of this model too. I guess there is also a table Student which you haven't informed us in the schema?

Comment: With the info that you provided I guess that you are looking for the recursive option http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive. If I remember correctly the default value is 0. Set it to 1 or 2 and see if this fits you.

Comment: @gmponos thanks you! When I will back home I will paste associations. Yesterday I test recursive = 2, and yes, with it User variables are printed but print too another relations that I don't want in this case

Comment: I rewrite some tables because my db was wrong and I test again recursive = 2. I think it's ok now. Here is my database design http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32238434/database-design-opinions-and-comments